# Time Complexity of Exponentiation Operation as per RAM Model of Computation

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, computation-models

Now, **$\color{blue}{\text{Exponentiation}}$** is defined as

> Exponentiation is a mathematical operation, written as $b^n$, involving two numbers, the base $b$ and the exponent or power $n$, and pronounced as "$b$ raised to the power of $n$".
> $$b^n = \underbrace{b\times b\times\cdot \cdots \times b}_{n\text{ times}}$$

---

Now, my primary question is that **What is the Time Complexity of Exponentiation Operation as per RAM Model of Computation?**

- As per [this](https://quastor.org/learn/time-complexity/ram-model-of-computation#:%7E:text=Subtraction%2C%20Multiplication%2C%20Division%2C-,Exponentiation,-Conditional%20Statements), RAM Model assumes a computer can do Exponentiation in a single unit-cost instruction. $(\mathcal{O}(1))$
- Intuitively, it appears to be of $\mathcal{O}(n)$
- Now, **What is the time complexity of in-built `pow` functions in many programming languages? One [comment](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/discuss/183770/O(1)-and-1-Line-Python/189331) claims it be of  $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$. And does `**` operator in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow) has the same complexity as that of `pow`?**

---

Adding to this, the $n^{th}$ [Fibonacci Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/fibonacci-number) can be computed in atleast four ways

- Using $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$, Time Complexity of this is essentially $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ [using [Master's Theorem]](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html)
- Using Memoization, Time Complexity of this is essentially $\mathcal{O}(n)$
- Using [Matrix Exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59922480), this they claim is $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$
- Solving Recurrence to get a Formula [often called as [Binet's Formula]](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula).
  $$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\bigg[{\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n}\bigg]$$
  **Now, will the Time Complexity using this formula be $\mathcal{O}(1)$?**

---

**TL;DR:** The three inter-related question are formatted using **Bold**. Since, the question is more of a convention, all relevant links are attached.

Comment: One question at a time, please. Also, help us to help you by telling what you've tried before or what seems to be puzzling. We're not a do-my-homework-for-me site.

Comment: You've probably heard of modular exponentiation, which calculates values in approximately $O(\log{n})$.  There are also multiple-base number systems (see Dual Base Number Systems or DBNS or related) which try to construct an exponent, say $c^n$ by exponents larger than 2, for example $c^{5^0} \cdot c^{5^2} \cdot c^{5^3}$.  I'm not an expert on this, but this may be a good place to start.  These multiple base number systems are primarily used when $n$ is a fixed constant known ahead of time, and $c$ is more like a variable number that changes for each function call.

Comment: As far as I know, modular exponentiation is generally the fastest method if $n$ is unknown, but the others can work well if $n$ is known.  Of course, the other methods can get NP-hard, and I think are still an area of active research.  There are also plenty of specialized methods, such as the cases when $c$ and $n$ are both integers.  The Chinese remainder theorem is useful for this, for example.

Comment: I hope you've found something interesting in my comments.  I can write more if you'd like.

Comment: You cannot exponentiate in time $O(1)$ in the RAM model, for the simple reason that the output doesn't fit a single machine word.

Comment: @Rohit Well, you know the answer. The time complexity depends on how you define RAM model of computation and how you implement the exponentiation. Another RAM model of computation is a particular piece of real modern hardware. I encourage you to write an answer following this approach.

Comment: @RickDecker There are only 3 inter-related question in the Text. They have been formatted using **bold** for clarity. Rest of Text is for Different Sources and Different Conventions. The question is not `homework` in any form. Question is more of a convention than solving, and my **try** can only be to look on Internet for different conventions.  And the same has been linked in the question.

Comment: @MattGroff Thanks for such a broad view of the topic. Your comments were very insightful. But I have three primary questions which are being formatted using **bold** in text. Based on your comments, can I say that answer of all three is $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$? And, your comments are interesting, it would be appreciated if you *post the comments* and *more details about the topic* as Answer to this Question, as community advises to avoid 'Extended Conversation on Comments'

Comment: Exponentiation can only be $O(1)$ for constant precision over constant sized fields (i.e. in case of overflow the behavior is non-standard). Now, an exact exponentiation $N^M$ of $n$-digit and $m$-digit numbers would require $\Omega(nM)=\Omega(n2^m)$ space and therefore $\Omega(n2^m)$ time.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for the Insight. But can we do Multiplication and Addition in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ in RAM Model? Multiple [sources](https://quastor.org/learn/time-complexity/ram-model-of-computation#:~:text=The%20operations%20that%20the%20RAM%20Model%20assumes%20a%20computer%20can%20do%20in%20a%20single%20unit%2Dcost%20instruction%20are) claim we can. I would be thankful if you could provide **more Insight about the topic** and **answer to three bold questions in text** as Answer to this post.

Comment: @JohnL. *So, can we say that there is no Universally Accepted Definition of RAM Model of Computation? And how many different versions do we have for RAM Model of Computation?* Since community advises to avoid eXtended conversation on comments, please try to post Answer of *italicized questions in comments* and **bold questions in text**. Thanks!

Comment: The common definition of the RAM model allows addition and multiplication of machine words in $O(1)$. This is part of the *definition* of the RAM model.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Then as per [this](https://quastor.org/learn/time-complexity/ram-model-of-computation) *definition* we can even do exponentiation in $\mathcal{O}(1)$.  Is there any standard definition of RAM Model? And if not, how many different versions do we have? I agree with [you](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148372/why-is-behavior-included-in-the-definition-of-a-data-structure/148377#comment311170_148372) that some definitions are not important.  But at the same time, definition for a Model of Computation, on which entire theory of calculating Time Complexity relies is important.

Comment: In any reasonable definition of the RAM machine, in $O(1)$ time you can only modify $O(1)$ machine words. The result of exponentiating two machine words fits in exponentially many machine words, so no reasonable definition of the RAM machine would allow it. I suggest ignoring your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to say first that I'm not an expert, but I find this question interesting.  I will focus on integer exponentiation.

Like the OP says, intuitively, exponentiation of integers should cost $O(n)$, since each multiplication should add a constant number of bits to the result.  For example, $8 \cdot 8$ in binary is $1000 \cdot 1000 = 1000000$ and any further multiplication by $8$ adds another 3 bits to the result.

If we use a *unit-cost* RAM model, we essentially assume that we can access any number in constant time, or $O(1)$.  Many scientists believe this model is unreasonable, because in this model it's easy to create giant numbers, and solve problems like multiplication in linear time or $O(n)$.  If you're curious about this, see [Martin Fürer's paper "How Fast Can We Multiply Large Integers on an Actual Computer?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1811).  In this paper, however, Dr. Fürer talks about other possible models, such as the log-cost RAM.  This model basically assumes it takes $O(\log{n})$ time to do an operation on an integer of size $n$.  This model seems to predict real life much better than the unit-cost RAM.  But remember, these are times for *multiplication*, not *exponentiation*.

---

So to make life easier, we can say multiplying a number $x$ takes time $M(x)$, where we replace the function $M(x)$ with either $O(1)$ or $O(\log{x})$, depending on the model.

Now we can focus more on exponentiation.  The simplest method that is better than naïve multiplication is [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).  The idea is to break the exponent into powers of 2.  The reason we do this is because it's easy to find $x^{2y}$ after we have found $x^y$.  Just square $x^y$ and you get $x^{2y}$.  This allows us to go through each power of 2 in the number $y$.  This will take time $\Theta(\log{y})$, and if we want to include the time to multiply, we'd write $O(M(x^y)\log{y})$.

---

**EDIT 8/7/2022**

I made a mistake in the time to multiply.  At each step, the time to multiply the $y^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number is $ M \left(x^{2^y} \right)$.  The time for all other algebraic activities is less than this, asymptotically.  It should be noted that the total time of modular exponentiation is

$$\begin{align}
\tag{1} \sum_{y=1}^n{ M(x^{2^y}) } &= M(x) + M(x^{2^1}) + M(x^{2^2}) + \dots + M(x^{2^n}) \\
\tag{2}                            &= \underbrace{M(x) + M(x^{2^1})}_{\le 2 M(x^{2^1})} + M(x^{2^2}) + \dots + M(x^{2^n}) \\
\tag{3}                            &\le \underbrace{2 M(x^{2^1}) + M(x^{2^2})}_{\le 2 M(x^{2^2})} + \dots + M(x^{2^n}) \\
\tag{4}                            &\le 2 M(x^{2^n}) \\
\end{align}$$

So, to summarize, the total time to calculate the $n^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number is proportional to the time it takes to multiply a single number the size of the $n^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number, or $O \left( M(x^{2^n}) \right)$.

Comment: Just as an aside, I may have more information regarding Dual-Base Number Systems (DBNS), but it may take awhile to collect my information.